# obexftp return code 97

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have been trying to send a file with bluetooth from my raspberry to my phone. I tried to use obexftp to do this but it gave me the return code 97. I have not been able to find out what this code means or what is causing this and would appreciate any insight on this matter.

The console in+output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ obexftp -b C0:EE:FB:24:43:03 -v -p test.wav
Browsing C0:EE:FB:24:43:03 ...
Connecting..\done
Tried to connect for 25ms
Sending "test.wav"...|failed: test.wav
The operation failed with return code 97
Disconnecting../done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a destination and a source in that order. Such as:

```
obexftp -b C0:EE:FB:24:43:03 -B 20 -c /some/dir/on_your/phone/ -p /full/path/to/this/test.wav
```

I remember it like -c is the "catcher" and -p is the "pitcher". The catcher is more important so it goes first. Think about it, your pitcher is pretty useless if there isn't a catcher.

http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/wiki/ObexFtpExamples

Answer (score 0):

Hello i got same problem i also get an error "Return code 68" what i foud out is, on "root" folder of my phone there are 2 "system folders":

```
root@chip:/home/chip# obexftp -b 1C:39:47:XX:XX:XX -B 20 -c / -l
Connecting..\done
Tried to connect for 562ms
Sending ""...|done
Receiving "(null)".../<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE folder-listing SYSTEM "obex-folder-listing.dtd"><folder-listing version="1.0"><folder name="PHONE_MEMORY"/><folder name="EXTERNAL_MEMORY"/></folder-listing>done
Disconnecting..-done
```

so there are 2 additional directories: PHONE_MEMORY and EXTERNAL_MEMORY - internal mem and SD card so after i put correct folder in -c switch i get following successfull result:

```
root@chip:/home/chip# obexftp -b 1C:39:47:XX:XX:XX -B 20 -c /PHONE_MEMORY/tmp -p /home/chip/setup.json
Connecting..\done
Tried to connect for 393ms
Sending ""...|Sending "PHONE_MEMORY".../Sending "tmp"...-done
Sending "/home/chip/setup.json"...\done
Disconnecting..|done
```